# Moving a cell value to another row based on ID numbers

Tags: sql

I am looking to move B to the above row. It can either be placed where the Null value is in Column B or another column can be created. The value of B is linked to value A through an ID. The ID for value B is always X + 2 (the values in the ID column are integers).

I can’t just move the value up because the table I am working with has thousands of rows. It must be linked to the ID’s.

Please let me know if you have any questions. Any assistance is much appreciated. Thank you.

| ID | Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| X | A | NULL |
| X+2 | NULL | B |

Keep in mind I am very new to SQL. Below is what I tried. It created a new column that only contains NULL values.

```
Select
   Column_B
From
   Table_Name
Where
   Table_Name.ID = Table_Name.ID +2 ) AS Col_B_Value
```

Comment: Do you want to get those values only when selecting or you want to update every row in the table?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a conditional subselect for that

```
UPDATE Table_Name T1
SET Column_B = (Select
   Column_B
From
   Table_Name
Where
   Table_Name.ID = T1.ID +2 )
WHERE Column_B IS NULL
```

Some databases could have a problem so you can make

```
UPDATE Table_Name T1
SET Column_B = (Select
   T2.Column_B
From
   (SELECT ID,Column_B  FROM Table_Name) T2
Where
   T2.ID = T1.ID +2 )
WHERE Column_B IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just do it with 2 updates statements

```
UPDATE Table
SET Column B = 'B'
WHERE ID = 'X'

UPDATE Table
SET Column B = NULL
WHERE ID = 'X+2'
```

If you need to do it in a select statement you could do it with a case statement too

```
SELECT ID,
Column A,
CASE WHEN ID = X AND Column B = NULL THEN 'B'
ELSE Column B END
FROM Table
```

Comment: no hea as in id 1 the columb as NULL and rowid 3 he has columnb as 6, so the 6 goes to id 1